# Use NestList instead of Do loop

Tags: programming

I am learning Gibbs sampling and imitating [this](https://youtu.be/a_08GKWHFWo?t=2m45s) explanation. Can we use `NestList`,`FoldList` or any other iterative function instead of `Do` loop for this code?

```
With[{ρ = 0.8, n = 10000}, Do[θ1[1] = 1; θ2[1] = 1; 
  θ1[i + 1] = RandomVariate@NormalDistribution[ρ θ2[i], 1 - ρ^2];
  θ2[i + 1] = RandomVariate@NormalDistribution[ρ θ1[i + 1], 1 - ρ^2], {i, 1, n - 1}]]

sim = Table[{θ1[i], θ2[i]}, {i, 1, 10000}];

Animate[Show[
  ListStepPlot[Take[sim, i], 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[Take[sim, i]]}, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}], 
  ContourPlot[
   PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 0.9}, {0.9, 1}}], {x, 
     y}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 25, 
   ContourShading -> None]], {i, 1, 100, 1}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

Comment: Why would you want to rewrite this without `Do`? You look only consists of side-effects (assigning a value). `NestList` can be used, but I don't see that it is more appropriate here. Btw, you are assigning `\[Theta]1[1] = 1;` and `\[Theta]2[1] = 1;` over and over again inside the loop. That is not necessary.

Comment: Ah, OK, I looked over the rest of your code. It seems your whole approach is not ideal and can be simplified. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I was just curious whether it can be done using more functional form. I am fine with Do loop. Thanks for suggestion for thetas, I'll put them outside of Do loop.

Comment: When I write `With[{\[Rho] = 0.8, {\[Theta]1[1], \[Theta]2[1]} = {1, 1}, n = 10000},Do[...stuff...]]` I get error. Do I have to write this outside of With? `{\[Theta]1[1], \[Theta]2[1]} = {1, 1};` Can use Block?

Comment: Try `With[{ρ = 0.8, n = 10000}, θ1[1] = 1; θ2[1] = 1; Do[*stuff*] ]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach with `NestList`. It should be equivalent to what you are achieving with the `Do` loop.

```
Module[{ρ = 0.8, n = 10000, nf},
  nf[arg_] := RandomVariate@NormalDistribution[ρ arg, 1 - ρ^2];
  sim = NestList[With[{theta1 = nf[#[[2]]]}, {theta1, nf[theta1]}] &, {1, 1}, n-1]
  ];
```

[image]

Comment: I see now. Do loop is more appropriate and more readable for this kind of iteration.